# wget download javascript link

Tags: javascript, wget

I'm writing a script to mirror certain pages of a website. Some of the pages include a javascript popup links with pages that need to be mirrored. For example, many of the pages that are being downloaded include links such as the following:

```
<a title="Click here" href="JavaScript:OpenTheWindow('/matric/grad/disciplin_pop.aspx?cod=121212','0')">The linked text</a>
```

The javascript file that defines "OpenTheWindow" is being downloaded OK by wget and functions in the mirrored pages, however I can't figure out how to download the files such as:

disciplin_pop.aspx?cod=121212

Is there something I can do?

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to write a script to extract the URI by a pattern and implement some of "OpenTheWindow" yourself if it transforms the URI, but the more you venture into this the more you'd need a html parser and JavaScript interpreter

Comment: I see. Yes, I'm managing to download them this way. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wget with js and did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001962/wget-with-js-and-did-not-work)