# Wget with js and did not work

Tags: javascript, wget

How do you download and save a page which is is dynamically generated from the command line? I tried

```
wget PageWithJS.com -O output.html
```

but output.html does not contain the dynamically generated code.

Answer (score 2):

wget does not execute JavaScript.

If you need the DOM as it loooks after Javascript rendering, use something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to download the page.